# Office-JS Word Add-in Document-to-sidebar communication

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I'm working on a taskpane add-in for Microsoft Word. So far, I'm able to place comments inside the Docx coming from the sidebar by abusing the OOXML insertion function.

I'm wondering if it's possible to monitor what the end user does with the comment.Is the commented deleted or accepted by the user? It is also significant to monitor the context of the comment - is that changed significantly?

I've considered the following approaches:

- Create a ContentControl for the context of the comment to which events can be hooked that check for selection and changes. The downside here is that these ContentControl affect the UI in word and are probably not understood by our end-user. Are there more 'background' ways to do this without affecting the UI too much?
- Create an interaction Hyperlink in the comment. I'm not sure if we can 'catch' this as an event or attach a JavaScript hook to this that actually makes it to the add-in?
- Poll the document at set intervals to determine if something has happened to the comment or the context of the comment. I'm not sure what the correct hooks for this would be, and how to accurately localize all the changes across the document.

Is there an approach that I missed?

I'm aware that adding these comments is on the roadmap for the office-js, but this has been the case for a couple of years so I'm not sure what the timeframe is for this.

### Edit

@Cindy thanks for taking the time to respond! With your help I've been able to get a functioning proof of concept using the hidden Content Control as a prepended OOXML snippet for the comment (So basically approach 1 combined with the OOXML insertion).

I can now capture some of the interaction by adding a binding to the content control and using the `EventType.BindingDataChanged`, something like this:

```
Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync("MyContentControlTest", "text", {}, function (result) {
                    if (result.status == "succeeded") {
                        result.value.addHandlerAsync (
                            Office.EventType.BindingSelectionChanged, function() 
                             {console.log("Don't touch me");}
                        )
                    })
})
```

It still feels a bit circumspect to attach a binding over a ContentControl, but I have not been able to add event listeners directly to the ContentControl. Given a named Content Control (MyContentControlTest) how could I attach an event [like the OnDataChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.contentcontrol?view=word-js-preview#ondatachanged)? And if i read correctly, this last feature is still in Preview, is there a way to find out what the expected release is?

Comment: It's possible to set a content control's appearance to "hidden" so that it's not visible to the user (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.contentcontrol?view=word-js-preview#appearance). Other than that, the third option is the only one that occurs to me and would mean caching the previous state, then comparing. Probably extracting the comment nodes from the Word Open XML. In order to identify them it might be necessary to rely on *bookmarks* inserted at the beginning of a comment; new comments wouldn't have them (until code adds them).